# Why my code doesnt compile if weeks ago worked perfectly?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have this simple school project that plays music selected through a menu with the 'PlaySound'command. 3 weeks ago it worked perfectly but now that I want to upgrade it it just won't compile. It says something like

> " [Linker error] C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAaBZrG.o:Proyecto.cpp:(.text+0x32d): undefined reference to `PlaySoundA@12 "

This is basically what it does, it just repeats for different genres/bands:
(Yes, I do have the music files inside the same folder as the program)

```
int PLAY1() {
  switch(CAN1) {
    case 1:
      system("cls");
      printf("\nNow playing: AKFG - Solanin (4:28)");
      PlaySound(TEXT("AKFG.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
      system ("pause");
      system("cls");
      ROC();
      break;
```

Comment: You have this tagged as C, but you're compiling as C++.  Perhaps you compiled the code with `PlaySound` as C, but `Proyecto.cpp` is looking for a C++ function?

Comment: If you've not changed the code since it worked three weeks ago, the problem is that something else changed — most probably the way that you compile the code, but possibly something was installed or uninstalled on the machine that is breaking the build process.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the code is actually compiling fine, from your output. The issue is with the linker. What ever library you were including that contains the definition for the function `PlaySound` is likely missing from your build/include step?

Are you sure you are using the exact build/link steps as you were previously?